# How to configure FTPS in IIS 7 & IIS 7.5 using Active Directory enabled One-to-One Client Certificate mapping

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, ftps

FTPS in IIS 7.5 is cool. Do you know how to configure it?

Comment: voted to migrate to serverfault.

Comment: Hello Andy. I am new to SO. What does voted to migrate mean? Is there a way I can push this to ServerFault, or do I need to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this 4 part tutorial...

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Client-Certificate-Mapping-in-FTP-75-Part-1.aspx

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Client-Certificate-Mapping-in-FTP-7-FTP-75-Part-2.aspx

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Client-Certificate-Mapping-in-FTP-7-FTP-75-Part-3.aspx

http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Configure-Client-Certificate-Mapping-in-FTP-7-FTP-75-Part-4.aspx

Hope this helps,
Rahul